# Converting integers to ASCII results in beeping and illegible text?

Tags: c#, type-conversion, character, ascii

I've never encountered a problem like this in a console application - I hear some rather frightening beeping, the program (and my computer) freezes momentarily, and then the console just stops working - it doesn't even print an error message.

I have [this text file](http://projecteuler.net/project/cipher1.txt). I read it as follows and then split the numbers into a list:

```
string path = @"C:\Users\owner\Documents\Quick Access\cipher1.txt";
string data = "";
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
{
    data = sr.ReadToEnd();
}

List<int> encryptedNums = new List<int>();
foreach (string s in data.Split(','))
{
    encryptedNums.Add(Convert.ToInt32(s));
}
```

Each number represents an ASCII character. I want to concatenate these numbers into a string:

```
string encryptedString = "";

//WTF???? 
foreach (int n in encryptedNums)
{
    encryptedString += (char)n;
}
```

The `foreach` loop results in some very weird conversions. By printing out the characters one by one and comparing them with an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), I see that the results are definitely *not* matching - for example, the number 2 results in a smiley-type figure. One of the conversions results in the beeping noise.

Here's what really stymies me. I have a separate method where I do essentially the same thing - I have a list of integers and I try to convert them to a string:

```
string s = "";
foreach (int n in decrypted)
{
    s += (char)n;
}
```

But this actually results in a proper string! I don't see where my error is, and why the first conversion fails, while the second conversion (and unless I'm missing something, the code is the same) is fine.

I'd appreciate any help.

The code that ultimately causes is the crash is printing `encryptedString`.

[Here is the full code.](http://pastebin.com/N4g64KWk)

Comment: I bet you want `n.ToString()` instead of `(char)n`

Comment: @AustinSalonen No, that would get me a string representation of the number.. I need the corresponding ASCII character.

Comment: Explanations of the downvotes would be appreciated. The content of the question may be specific and localized but the question itself (I believe) is formulated generically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the second works and the first does not is the value of `n` is different.

Visible letters will be in the range of 32 to 126 (and 9, 10 and 13 for `\t`, `\n`, and `\r` respectively), if you are not getting ints in that range you are doing the "decryption" incorrectly (from your code example, you have not done any decryption at all).

You must do something to the list of ints in the text file to make it legeable text.

Comment: The file contains numbers outside that range though.

Comment: @NoToast It's supposed to, he is attempting to complete [Project Euler Problem 59](http://projecteuler.net/problem=59). The goal is figure out the 3 letter key that makes the above key only have values that are legeable text.

Comment: You're correct, my logic was flawed and I was trying to print our a string that was not designed to be printable/readable.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Ah, I see. I was not familiar with that problem.

Comment: I solved the problem :). The entire exercise of trying to print the original text was irrelevant to the solution, the actual error in my code was in the Decrypt method, I was reseting the index to 2 (just a typo) when it should have been 0.

Comment: @L.B Its a 24 bit key, just brute force it and try all the combinations (that is the worst case solution there are some tricks I can think of to make it faster.)

Comment: @L.B I'm not entirely sure what you mean.. Are you implying that I should post my solution? Because it's irrelevant to the actual question being asked. My solution (for those interested) was to decrypt the message with all possible passcodes (there are 26^3), check all decryptions for the word "the" (this check isn't in the code I posted), then manually check each decryption with the word "the" to see if it is valid English - there weren't many to check.

Comment: The way I would solve it is create a `HashSet` for each byte in the key. Then I would walk through the ciphertext removing all values from the `HashSet` of the byte that I am testing that would cause the letter I am XORing to be an illageal character. By the end of the process I would either have 1 value in each `HashSet` or I would have only a handful of values to try and I could just inspect them myself to see which ones where gibberish and which ones made sense.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain That's a rather creative and interesting solution.. I might implement it later to see how effective it is. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: You can make it even faster by only testing values still in the `HashSet` instead of testing 0-255 every time (forgot to mention that) (But don't forget you can't modifiy a collection inside a foreach loop, the easist fix for that is `foreach(byte testByte in bytesToTest.ToList())` the `.ToList()` is a LINQ function will make a copy of the hashset and use that to loop over, that way you can do `bytesToTest.Remove(testByte)` inside the foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the bell character or `'\7'`.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character

Printing that character usually results in a beep and doing so multiple times in a short time span causes the application to freeze on most systems.

Comment: Don't tell someone if they [should use a shoe or glass bottle](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/archive/2005/05/25/408925.aspx), tell them to get a hammer!

Comment: I agree, but the bell character is still a cool thing to know about and my answer was valid. I feel that the downvote was unjustified.

Comment: A downvote is described as "This answer is not useful" Explaining the bell charater, while interesting, is not useful for solving the OP's problem of ***why*** he is getting illegible text.

Comment: For the record, I agree. I accepted Scott's answer because it helped me solve my immediate problem (the beeping was sort of a side issue) but NoToast's answer was very helpful, was relevant to the question, and improved my general knowledge.. The down vote was definitely unjustified.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain You're mistaken - the information and the link he supplied did help me understand. He didn't baby-feed me the answer but he gave me the resources to find it all the same.